# Pinia in Nuxt3 middleware

Tags: middleware, pinia, nuxt3

I'm getting this error:

> 500 []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia.
> Did you forget to install pinia? const pinia = createPinia()
> app.use(pinia) This will fail in production.

## **middleware/auth:**

```
import {
  abortNavigation,
  defineNuxtRouteMiddleware,
  navigateTo,
  useNuxtApp,
} from "nuxt/app";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { useAuthStore } from "~/store/authStore";
/* const { isAuthenticated } = storeToRefs(useAuthStore()); // make authenticated state reactive */

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = storeToRefs(useAuthStore());

  // if token exists and url is /login redirect to homepage
  if (isAuthenticated && to?.name === "login") {
    return navigateTo("/");
  }

  // if token doesn't exist redirect to log in
  if (!isAuthenticated && to?.name !== "login") {
    abortNavigation();
    return navigateTo("/login");
  }
});
```

I'm trying to make my backend auth api works with this middleware, but I'm getting the error shared above.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, would you mind providing us your store configuration? That would be helpful for others to debug your issue.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.